# awk or sed to lowercase/uppercase only one character in string?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Is there a way how to uppercase/lowercase only one character in some string?

Input Example:

```
syslog_apr_24_30
syslog_mar_01_17
```

Desired output:

```
syslog_Apr_24_30
syslog_Mar_01_17
```

Note please the uppercase beginning of the month.

I have tried `awk` but I'm not good enough to get it working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `\u` in GNU sed to uppercase a letter:

```
sed -e 's/_\(.\)/_\u\1/' input
```

Perl does the same:

```
perl -pe 's/_(.)/_\u$1/' input
```

`\l` does the opposite.

Comment: A touch simpler: `sed 's/_./\U&/'`

Answer (score 5):

`Awk` version with substrings and toupper

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="_"} {
        cap=toupper(substr($2,1,1));
        lower=substr($2,2,3);
        $2 = cap lower; print 
}' list.txt
```

Sample run:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="_"} { 
    cap=toupper(substr($2,1,1));
    lower=substr($2,2,3);$2 = cap lower; print 
}' list.txt               
syslog_Apr_24_30
syslog_Mar_01_17
```

Answer (score 4):

### awk:

```
echo "syslog_apr_24_30" | 
  awk -F'_' '{print $1"_"toupper(substr($2,1,1)) substr($2,2)  "_"$3"_"$4}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Perl approach:

```
$ perl -pe 's/_./uc($&)/e' file
syslog_Apr_24_30
syslog_Mar_01_17
```

The `-p` causes each line to printed after applying the script given by `-e`. The substitution replaces the first instance of `_` and the character following it with themselves (`$&` is whatever was matched) upper cased (`uc()`), The `e` at the end of the substitution operator (`s///e`) is needed in order to evaluate expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F_ '{
    printf "%s_%s_%s_%s",$1,toupper(substr($2,1,1))substr($2,2,2),$3,$4"\n"
}' foo
```

or

```
awk -F_ '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if(i==2){
            printf "%s",toupper(substr($i,1,1))substr($i,2,length($i)-1)
        } 
        else {printf "%s",$i} 
        if(i<NF) {printf "%s","_"}
    } printf "%s","\n"}' foo
```

---

*Example*

```
% cat foo
syslog_apr_24_30
syslog_mar_01_17

% awk -F_ '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if(i==2){printf "%s",toupper(substr($i,1,1))substr($i,2,length($i)-1)} else {printf "%s",$i} if(i<NF) {printf "%s","_"}} printf "%s","\n"}' foo
syslog_Apr_24_30
syslog_Mar_01_17

% awk -F_ '{printf "%s_%s_%s_%s",$1,toupper(substr($2,1,1))substr($2,2,2),$3,$4"\n"}' foo 
syslog_Apr_24_30
syslog_Mar_01_17
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `perl`:

```
perl -F_ -anle '$F[1] = ucfirst $F[1];print join "_", @F'
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash 4.x, using a regex to pick out the part you want to upcase, and the `^^` upcase operator on that part.  Tacking on the front and back (matched by .*) to re-create the whole string:

```sh
foo=syslog_apr_24_30
if [[ $foo =~ (.*)(_[a-z])(.*) ]]; then
    foo=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]^^}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
fi
```

If you don't remember all the quoting rules, it's safe to quote everything except the regex (which would make `=~` do a literal string-match).

The `^` upcase-first operator only works at the beginning of a variable (or array element).  And there doesn't seem to be any substring expansion that gives you what perl would call an lvalue (that you can assign to / modify).  The up/downcase-first operators can take a pattern that's matched on a per-character basis, but that doesn't help skipping over `syslog_`, because there are month names that start with characters in "syslog".

Anyway, this might be faster than `foo="$(echo "$foo" | sed 's/_./\U&/')"` (posted as a comment to the accepted answer, by Glenn Jackman).

Bash, sed, or awk will be MANY times faster than perl.  If you start finding multiple perl one-liners useful in a shell script, you should just write the whole thing in perl.

Answer (score 0):

If the month always follows the first "_" (underscore), then use this (as shown in other answers):

```
sed -e 's/_\(.\)/_\u\1/'
```

If there may be other underscores before the one preceding the month then the above won't work.

If the month always begins with the 8th character, then use this:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\{7\}\)\(.\)/\1\u\2/'
```