# Rename a specific component of filename from lowercase to uppercase

Tags: mv

I have a directory with several files named as follow:

```
London_qle_merged
Paris_qle_merged
Tokyo_qle_merged
London_qle_obs
Paris_qle_merged
Tokyo_qle_merged
```

How can I rename the file having *merged in the filename as follow:

```
London_Qle_merged
Paris_Qle_merged
Tokyo_Qle_merged
```

I know that I could do a loop as follow:

```
for name in Paris London Tokyo do;
  mv ${name}_qle_merged ${name}_Qle_merged
done
```

but is there no other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. In ksh/Bash/zsh:

```
for f in *_merged; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f/_qle_/_Qle_}" 
done
```

or in standard shell.

```
for f in *_qle_merged; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%_qle_merged}_Qle_merged" 
done
```

See also, e.g. [Parameter Expansion in BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by combination of awk and tr

Command

```
find . -type f -iname "*merged" |tr -d "./" | awk -F "_" '{print "mv" " " $1"_"$2"_"$3 " " $1"_"toupper(substr($2,1,1))substr($2,2)"_"$3 }' | sh
```

Below merged files

```
London_qle_merged
Paris_qle_merged
Tokyo_qle_merged
```

renamed to

```
London_Qle_merged
Paris_Qle_merged
Tokyo_Qle_merged
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job with no script loops, spawning just a single sub-process:

```
rename 's/qle/Qle/' *_merged
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rename` command is your friend here. It is `sed` for file names. (ensure that you have the Larry Wall version, there is at least two programs with this name).

The following answer is for file content, and thus uses `sed`. I have used it and re-purposed it to `rename`.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211579/4778

```
rename  -e 's/_(.)/_\u$1/' *_merged
```

It up cases the letter immediately following the first `_`.

A simpler solution for this specific input

```
rename 's/qle/Qle/' *_merged
```